# Wordpress post update causing encoding issue?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, encoding, utf-8

I'm using Wordpress and just encountered a weird character encoding issue. The content gets submitted to the database ok but after the updating the post, the encoding gets wacky.

Here's how the encoding should look:

[image]

And here's how it *actually* looks:

[image]

Specs are WP 4.3, Encoding UTF8mb4 in our 5.6.23 MySQL database and collation is unset.

Comment: what theme are you using? Try using a default theme and see if the issue goes away.

Comment: What your connection parameters for getting to MySQL?

Comment: @Ejay thanks for the suggestion, using a custom theme, will give default theme a shot and let you know.

Comment: @RickJames IN wp-config.php, `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');` and `define('DB_COLLATE', '');` but we've changed the collate parameter and didn't help.

Comment: Is there a `<meta ... charset=UTF-8>` in all the WP web pages?

Comment: @RickJames believe so. is there such thing as `<meta ... charset=UTF-8mb4>` ?

Comment: No.  In that context, `UTF-8` includes the mb4 stuff.  Only MySQL forgot to include the extra planes.

Comment: Turn off mbstring.encoding_translation?

Comment: `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ... WHERE ...` -- I would like to see the hex for something that is coming through "wrong".  It will determine whether the data is stored correctly.

Comment: also, are we talking about frontend here? Does the data look ok in backend edit screen?

Comment: @RickJames thanks so much for your suggestions, I'm still investigating...